# Inline CSS image transition

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the following effect: below CSS, on hover, does a "slot machine effect" that rolls the icon in a vertical carousel (please see the css below for details).
Due to restrictions of hosting that I am using for my website, I cannot use any external library of icons, so I would like to achieve the same effect, pasting the css into the header and using it with an `img` tag in HTML.

Could you please help me trim this css so that it will actually work with my image?

Thank you for all your forbearance and help.

```
-webkit-transition:all .3s;
-o-transition:all .3s;
transition:all .3s
}
.btn.social_share:hover .social-media-share-buttons-icon:before {
    top: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}
.btn.social_share:hover .social-media-share-buttons-icon:after {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}
.btn.social_share:active {
    text-decoration: none!important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
}
.btn.social_share:active .social-media-share-buttons-icon {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}
.btn.social_share:active .social-media-share-buttons-icon:before {
    top: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}
.btn.social_share:active .social-media-share-buttons-icon:after {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}
.btn.social_share.facebook .social-media-share-buttons-icon:after,
.btn.social_share.facebook .social-media-share-buttons-icon:before {
    content: "\e63f"
}
.btn.social_share.linkedin .social-media-share-buttons-icon:after,
.btn.social_share.linkedin .social-media-share-buttons-icon:before {
    content: "\e631"
}
.btn.social_share.twitter .social-media-share-buttons-icon:after,
.btn.social_share.twitter .social-media-share-buttons-icon:before {
    content: "\e640"
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeBottom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(10%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
        transform: translateY(10%)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeBottom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(10%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
        transform: translateY(10%)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeBottom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(10%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
        transform: translateY(10%)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}
```

As requested, also adding the HTML snippet, which currently is not working with above css:

```
<div style="padding: 30px 0; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; text-align: center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="social-media-share-buttons">
                    <li>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.mywebsite.com" class="btn btn-link social_share facebook" rel="nofollow" data-social_name="facebook" data-post_id="" data-social_type="share" data-location="inline">
        <img class="social-media-share-buttons-icon" src="facebook_icon.png">
        <div style="color: #fff; line-height: 2; font-weight: 700;">Facebook</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: By "inline" do you mean NOT in a stylesheet or `style` tag? Basically, NO.

Comment: Can you share your html also, please?

Comment: @RicardoFerreira HTML added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need animations for that. Just use transitions and transforms and it works: Here some example:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4456aa;
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

a div {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

a img {
  transition: all ease 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

a:hover {
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

a:hover img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="social-media-share-buttons">
  <li>
    <a target="_blank"
       href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.mywebsite.com"
       class="btn btn-link social_share facebook"
       rel="nofollow"
       data-social_name="facebook"
       data-post_id=""
       data-social_type="share"
       data-location="inline">
        <img class="social-media-share-buttons-icon" 
             src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/20/20837.png">
        <div>Facebook</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

You may use pre-built CSS properties like transforms and transitions, maybe they make you independent of animations.

Comment: sure I can do that, but what exactly should I put in there? the css that I pasted won't work with my image, I already tried that

Comment: I thought you have a problem with inline css. Didn't get you properly. @CodeRage